# Convert GST time to local browser time

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a GST time from a server in following format.

```
2015-06-09 09:07 PM
```

My requirement is to convert this time to local browser time using Javascript.

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have u tried anything?Share with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use ISO 8601 for dates, as this is the default for Javascript Date class:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

In case you can't change the server code you will have to parse it manually, try something like this:

```
var dateTime = '2015-06-09 09:07 PM';

var splittedTime = dateTime.split(' ');
var date = splittedTime[0];
var time = splittedTime[1] + ' ' + splittedTime[2];
var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
if (AMPM == 'PM' && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
if (AMPM == 'AM' && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
var sHours = hours.toString();
var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
if (hours < 10) sHours = '0' + sHours;
if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = '0' + sMinutes;
// GST is GMT +4
time = new Date(date + 'T' + sHours + ':' + sMinutes + '+0400');
// Should be in local time
time.toString();
```

That should give you a time in local time.